# Where is it best to place the code that initializes my UI for an OS X app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

If I am *NOT* using NIB/XIB files for my UI then where is it best to place/launch the code that initialises my GUI?

The logical place seems to be the App Delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method...or perhaps there is a window controller or delegate that should be used? Or perhaps in the main.swift file?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what your program does and the preffered order of operations.

If you want to call a view controller right away then you can put it in the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method like you mentioned but you could also put it in methods of other classes if you want something some operations to run in the background first.

The main thing to remember is that you want the user to feel like your application isn't frozen. So add a progress indicator or such if it will be a longer loading time than average. Apple requires a loading screen for all published iOS apps so that is a perfect place to put a loading image.

Comment: How would the nib loading time compare to the time of loading the view hierarchy through code?

Comment: I can't tell you with certainty but I assume it's negligible. You can check out this link http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/load-from-nib-or-construct-views-in.html?m=1 or debug the load times yourself for your own project though.